# How to dynamically load an external module in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, portal

I'm quite new to Angular 2 and Typescript.  At the moment I'm evaluating Angular 2 for a highly modular application suite.  One basic requirement is to load external plug-ins (portlets, modules, whatever you name it) at runtime.

Possible sequence:

1. The user starts the app, enters the hostname of the server he want to connect to.
2. App connects to the server and loads a specific JS file (or set of files)
3. App starts the module contained in the newly loaded files.

Steps 1 & 2 are no problem.  Loading the script is currently done by simply adding a script-tag to the header (not sure if there are better ways?).

But I'm totally stuck with step three.  How can I programmatically start the NgModule from this downloaded script?

Comment: Angular 2 is in no way highly modular. NgModule introduces tight coupling, rigidity

Comment: you can do this by creating multiple modules and using [module lazy loading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load)